# DotNet folder is missing from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to load a .Net Core project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (with update 3) but I get this error:

[image]

The DotNet folder is missing from location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0`

I have Tried repairing visual studio and reinstalling update 3, as well as .Net Core, but to no avail.

What part of Visual Studio do I need to fix the installation on, in order to get the DotNet folder to appear where it should?

Comment: getting the exact same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Microsoft.Net Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 which fixed this issue for me.